# Upload rate limit on Dailymotion API

Tags: php, upload, dailymotion-api

After an upload, the `Dailymotion API` return this error :

> You reached your upload rate limit, please slow down.

That was the second upload of the journey, the first was for the same video.
The video size is about `700 MB`, and the duration is `2 hours`.
The account is not official.
The first upload didn't sent that error, and another try some days after not any more.

So what limit has been reached?

Comment: What do you mean the account is not official?  I am confused by your question, honestly.

Comment: Official is the status of the account. It's sometimes indicated on pages with a green notch on the side of the user's name.
Official users have some privileges and they can have some differences on the upload limits.
Here is a FAQ for Official users :
http://official.dailymotion.com/fr/faqs_no_header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current limit is of 4 video per hour and 2 hours per day, so you probably reached the duration limit. 
For most users, the duration limit per video is of 3600 seconds and 2Gb per video, but all those rules may vary on a case-by-case basis.

You can check you limits per video using the api call: 
https://api.dailymotion.com/user/me?fields=limits&access_token=TOKEN where `TOKEN` is an access token of your user with the `userinfo` scope

Comment: Thank for your answer.
I just tried this, and the response is :
{"limits":{"video_duration":0,"video_size":0}}
SO, there is no limit ?

Answer (score 0):

yes its limited by 120minutes long, 12 videos max, 120minutes per day, the limits are for all accounts, normal and partners